# Configure iOS MDM Profile to make periodic network calls

Tags: ios, mdm

Through MDM Profile on the iOS Device, can we make periodic network calls to the server. ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt what you are trying to achieve using MDM profile or protocol is directly possible.

MDM uses push notification to cause device to poll the MDM server whenever it is necessary. This is a deliberate design decision by Apple to conserve battery power and data. That said there are possibilities to circumvent this.

1. Use MDM push notifications to make devices query the MDM server periodically. This will place the onus of initiation on the MDM server itself. It can add cost because sending push notification is charged by Apple. Consult Apple's documentation on MDM profile, especially 'During Normal Operation' section.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH3-SW2

2. Alternatively, you can use MDM in an enterprise setting to push an app on the device(s) which will periodically fetch content from a server, effectively polling the server.  Consult app background task and fetch task.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Either-way, it will be best that you test battery consumption of your solution before mass deploying it.

Also, it may make sense if you can elaborate your original problem a bit. At times these specific questions can be a XY Problem.

Comment: This is for an enterprise application,
There is an application that runs in background to do that polling, but we wanted that to happen through the profile instead of app.
App running in background polling for commands is draining the battery, its playing a sample music file to keep the app alive in background, is there any better way of doing this ?